# Tor and uBlock Origin

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Why isn't there an adblocker included in Tor browser by default? I don't know a single person below the age of 70 that doesn't use an adblocker. After reading around for a while all I have been able to find has been conversations from half a decade ago that basically boil down to "I want ublock origin" vs "I dont want ublock origin". Is there an actual technical reason for not including it? Ads are pretty much the only thing that manages to drive me off the Tor Browser. I should add that I am aware adding an adblocker alters your fingerprint which is why I would like to see one included by default. I know that noscript can stop some ads but I still get lots of ads even on safest

Answer (score 0):

The extensions can be enumerated and/or detected by the running website's scripts, so it would create a fingerprinting criteria for Tor Browser users. You're free to use any add-ons of your choice, but it **must not** be a wide list of the add-ons shipped out of the box with Tor Browser, because many unexperienced users will just use it as it is and it will fingerprint them the better the wider the pre-shipped add-ons list, even if they are very sane and useful.

Comment: But isn't that also the case with NoScript? By including ublock with tor with a preset list of rules that should ensure all tor users look the same from my understanding. In fact I would argue it reduces the fingerprinting criteria because you wont have some users installing ublock, some installing ablock and some not installing anything.

Comment: it's a case for *anything*, actually - and, sadly...